# Terminology: How would you describe the type T for Nullable<T>?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, terminology, nullable

When talking about a generic type, `Foo<T>`, `T` is called the *generic argument* or *type argument* of generic type `Foo` in the .NET `System.Type` documentation.

Now, when I am dealing with a type such as `int?` or `Nullable<Bar>`, how do I refer to the generic argument (i.e. `int` or `Bar` in my example) when describing the type?

I'd call it **the base type** of the nullable type, but *base type*  is usually used to refer to the parent class, when describing a class hierarchy... so I don't feel it is right to be talking about a base type here. And using the terminology *the generic argument* of the nullable type makes me feel to general.

So how do you speak about these types?

And more specifically, how would you name this extension method:

```
public static System.Type GetXxxType(this System.Type type)
{
    if ((type.IsGenericType) &&
        (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition () == typeof (System.Nullable<>)))
    {
        return type.GetGenericArguments ()[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When passed a `Nullable<T>` this method returns `typeof(T)` as a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the spec:

> A nullable type can represent all
>   values of its **underlying** type plus an
>   additional null value. A nullable type
>   is written T?, where T is the
>   underlying type

Edit:

reference: 
C# 4 spec section **4.1.10 Nullable types**